# How to get a specific value from a pivot table - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

How do I get a specific value from a pivot table?
I need to store  **"imdb_score"** as a int in a variable.
how can I do this?

this is the the contents of the table:

```
                  country_id     director_id      duration      gross     id_x  id_y    imdb_score    title_year
director_name                               
Christopher Nolan     1              16          143.428571  2.494235e+08   1   16         8.6       2007.857143
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the index to the unique column you have in dataframe which you want to use to filter.

```
var=df.loc['Christopher Nolan','imdb_score']
```